# Error in my code for calculating how far light has traveled

Tags: java

I need to make a program that generates 5 lines of output regarding how far light has traveled (in a vacuum) since the Unix epoch, at the time that the program is run.

1. The string: "Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...".
2. The number of kilometers, assuming the speed of light to be exactly 299792458 m/s: x.xxx km.
3. The number of astronomical units, assuming 149597870700.0 m/au: x.xxx au.
4. The number of light years, assuming 9460730472580800.0 m/ly: x.xxx ly.
5. The number of parsecs, assuming 3.085677581e16 m/pc (note that 3.085677581e16 is Java's way of representing 3.085677581⋅10^16 in normal scientific notation):
   x.xxx pc.

In my code, I get an error on the integer being too high and have trouble using the print method. Can anyone help?

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Assignment02.java:16: error: integer number too large: 9460730472580
     long ly = km / 9460730472580;
                    ^
Assignment02.java:20: error: ')' expected
        "Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled..."
                                                     ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: not a statement
        (km), au, ly, pc);
         ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: ';' expected
        (km), au, ly, pc);
           ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: not a statement
        (km), au, ly, pc);
              ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: ';' expected
        (km), au, ly, pc);
                ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: not a statement
        (km), au, ly, pc);
                  ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: ';' expected
        (km), au, ly, pc);
                    ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: not a statement
        (km), au, ly, pc);
                      ^
Assignment02.java:25: error: ';' expected
        (km), au, ly, pc);
```

This is my code:

```
public class Assignment02  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

    // Stores the return value of System.currentTimeMillis() in variab$
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Calculation of how far light has travelled until "now" in kilometer$
    long km = (299792 * now)/1000 ;
    // Calculatuion of how far light has travelled until "now" in astronomical units$
    long au =  km / 149597870;
    // Calculation of how far light has travelled until "now" in light years$
    long ly = km / 9460730472580;
    // Calculation of how far light has traveled until "now" in parsecs
    long pc = km / 3.085677581e16;
    System.out.printf(
      "Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled..."+
      "%d km"+
      "%d au"+
      "%d ly"+
      "%d pc",
      (km), au, ly, pc);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix compile errors and print statement like this:

- Added `L` to end of large integer value to make it a `long` literal.
- Added cast to `long` to convert `double` value.
- Added `%n` to print format string to add newlines in output.

```java
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long km = (299792 * now)/1000 ;
long au =  km / 149597870;
long ly = km / 9460730472580L;
long pc = (long) (km / 3.085677581e16);
System.out.printf("Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...%n"+
                  "%d km%n"+
                  "%d au%n"+
                  "%d ly%n"+
                  "%d pc",
                  (km), au, ly, pc);
```

Of course, you might actually want to output `double` values, not `long` values:

```java
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long km = (299792 * now)/1000 ;
long au =  km / 149597870;
double ly = km / 9460730472580d;
double pc = km / 3.085677581e16;
System.out.printf("Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...%n"+
                  "%d km%n"+
                  "%d au%n"+
                  "%.1f ly%n"+
                  "%f pc",
                  (km), au, ly, pc);
```

*Output*

```
Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...
451349163977648 km
3017082 au
47.7 ly
0.014627 pc
```

Comment: My calculations are wrong, they are supposed to come out like this "451350334965050.750 km,
3017090.637 au,
47.708 ly,
14.627 pc". Any idea how?

Comment: I have added the decimal values but now getting a new error. Assignment02.java:16: error: ';' expected
     long ly = km / 9460730472580.800L;
                                        ^

Comment: @C.Mustang Remove the `L`. It denotes a `long` literal, but you're giving it a `double` value. The `.` automatically makes the literal a `double`, so no need for "type"-letter at the end. You should read the chapter on numeric literal values in whatever Java guide you are reading. Or read the definitive source, the Java Language Specification, [§3.10. Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).

Answer (score 1):

#### Integer number too large

When you compile your code, you get this error:

```
:12: error: integer number too large: 9460730472580
    long ly = km / 9460730472580;
                   ^
1 error
```

The compiler is telling you that the number you're dividing by is too large to be an integer, so you need to use a larger data type.

In this case, you can tell the compiler that it's explicitly a long by appending the L suffix like so:

```
long ly = km / 9460730472580L;
```

#### The print method

Your print method will not put things on separate lines just because you split up the string in your code. You need to use line separators like `"%n"` or use something like `System.out.println` to put your outputs on separate lines.

#### Possible loss of precision

However, even if you fix the "integer number is too large" error, you'll still not be compiling due to this error:

```
:14: error: possible loss of precision
    long pc = km / 3.085677581e16;
                 ^
  required: long
  found:    double
```

This is happening because your division operation will result in a double, and you're trying to stuff it into a long. Your options either are to change the data type of `pc` to `double` (and update your print statement), or to cast the calculation to a `long`:

```
// either change the data type:
double pc = km / 3.085677581e16;

// or cast the result:
long pc = (long)(km / 3.085677581e16);
```

The reason the loss of precision is important is because the number of parsecs is actually less than 1. Since you're storing that value as a long, you're going to end up with a value of 0.

This is why you might want to consider switching your data type for this field to a double so you can display the result of your calculation more accurately.

#### Result

Your output will look something like this:

```
Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...
451349237824811 km
3017083 au
47 ly
0 pc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigInteger` (and/or `BigDecimal`) instead of `long`, something like this:

```
public class Assignment02
{
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Stores the return value of System.currentTimeMillis() in variab$
        final BigInteger now = BigInteger.valueOf( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        // Calculation of how far light has travelled until "now" in kilometer$
        final BigInteger km = BigInteger.valueOf( 299792 ).multiply( now )
                              .divide( BigInteger.valueOf( 1000 ) );
        // Calculatuion of how far light has travelled until "now" in astronomical units$
        final BigInteger au = km.divide( BigInteger.valueOf( 149597870 ) );
        // Calculation of how far light has travelled until "now" in light years$
        final BigInteger ly = km.divide( BigInteger.valueOf( 9460730472580L ) );
        // Calculation of how far light has traveled until "now" in parsecs
        final BigDecimal pc = new BigDecimal( km )
                              .divide( BigDecimal.valueOf( 3085677581L, -7 ),
                                       new MathContext( 5 ) );
    System.out.printf( "Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...%n" +
                       "%d km%n%d au%n%d ly%n%f pc%n",
                       km, au, ly, pc );
}
```

Output:

```
Since the Unix epoch, light has traveled...
451349466051964 km
3017084 au
47 ly
0,014627 pc
```